# How to get content (buffer) from email attachments array using node.js? I need to put in: Buffer.from(content, 'base64') afterwards

Tags: node.js, email-attachments

How to get content (buffer) from object of email attachments array using node.js?

```
contentType: "text/plain"
charset: "utf-8"
fileName: "Steps.txt"
contentDisposition: "attachment"
transferEncoding: "base64"
generatedFileName: "Steps.txt"
contentId: "ae014dad249f6f721f2a964c21dc3abf@mailparser"
checksum: "644b83d265aa6ec17093ae0636861481"
length: 1294
content: buffer[1294]
```